# Use "upgraded Elastic Search" version in an existing project

Tags: elasticsearch

Please help me to find out that I want to apply upgraded version of Elastic Search in my existing project in which I already used the previous version of it. Which kind of changes required in code to make it possible? I am new in this technology.

Comment: It depends from which older version to which newer version you're upgrading, but you can find the full list of [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) and check your code and queries to make sure you're up-to-date.

Comment: thanks, let me try it..it may proves valuable.

Comment: Thank for this link but It says about what should do after applying upgraded Elastic Search in project but my question is : How to apply that upgraded version in existing project.Does it require coding modification or something else.

Comment: No, if you look at each "Breaking changes in x.y"  links to the right, you'll get the list of changes you need to pay attention to **BEFORE** attempting an upgrade.

Comment: I am working on Maven project using Elastic Search 1.4.0 and now migrate on version 2.3.1 So now where should I make changes in my project to convert in the needed version. Like now I am using dependency for 1.4.0 and ElasticSearchClient also, so now I don't  know that where and which changes make it possible....

Comment: There are **many** changes between 1.4.0 and 2.3.1. You should go through all links ["Breaking changes in 1.6"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-1.6.html) through ["Breaking changes in 2.3"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.3.html) and make sure your code is compliant. Then in your pom.xml file, you can change the dependency from 1.4 to 2.3 and try to build your project.

Comment: There are some errors I find after changing the dependency.

Comment: Error:(30, 53) java: package org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.status does not exist

Comment: Error:(35, 43) java: package org.elasticsearch.action.termvector does not exist

Comment: Error:(36, 43) java: package org.elasticsearch.action.termvector does not exist
Error:(41, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImmutableSettings
  location: package org.elasticsearch.common.settings
Error:(48, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IndexMissingException
  location: package org.elasticsearch.indices

Comment: Follow the links I gave you, no magic there, it will take a bit of time.

Comment: thanks valentinc, I read these links and now I understand the basic functionality of Elastic Search migration process.. now will you help me to find out those errors solution in my project. Bcoz I checked this errors and these files and variables are missing and some are depricated in upgraded version 2.3.0. so what to do to know about this functions in new version? Is there something new files which replaces those in previous version...?

Comment: Thanks I get it.. all answers found.

Comment: In version 2.x when I replaced IndexMissingException by IndexNotFoundException as the document says..but it gives error.. what to do?